# Awk flag to remove unwanted data

Tags: bash, awk

another awk question.

I have a large text file that is separated by numerical values

```
43   47
abc
efg
hig
21   122
hijk
lmnop

39 41
somemore
texthere
```

what i would like to do is print the text only if a condition is satisfied.

here's what i have tried, with no luck

```
awk '{a=$1; b=$2; if (a < 43 && a > 37 && b < 52 && b > 41) {f=1} elif (a > 43 && a < 37 && b > 52 && b < 41) {print; f=0} } f' file
```

I'd like to print all of the text if the statement is satisfied and i'd like to skip the text if the statement isn't satisfied.

desired output from above

```
43   47
abc
efg
hig


39 41
somemore
texthere
```

Comment: One of your `if` statements tests `a < 43`, the next one tests `a > 43`. What if `a == 43`? You're never checking for an exact match.

Comment: `a > 43 && a < 37` is impossible. How can a number be higher than 43 and also lower than 37 at the same time? You must have meant `||`. But maybe that should just be `else` rather than `elif`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    # on a line with 2 numbers:
    NF == 2 && $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {
        # set a flag if the numbers fall in the given ranges
        f = (37 <= $1 && $1 <= 43 && 41 <= $2 && $2 <= 52)
    }
    f
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Self-explanining solution:

```
awk '
    function inrange(x, a, b) { return a <= x && x <= b }
    /^[0-9]+[\t ]+[0-9]/ {
        f = inrange($1, 37, 43) && inrange($2, 41, 52)
    }
    f
'
```